# Get text of CCLabelTTF

Tags: iphone

I have multiple scenes in my iphone game. In one of the scene which is the SelectLevelMenu scene I have shown the level number in a CCLabelTTF. Now I want to use this value in my StartGame scene which will run according to the value I got from the label.
However, I am unable to get the text of label. Once I get this value, I can assign it to a variable which I can use to switch levels.
All I want is how to get the text of CCLabelTTF.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NSString *str = [cclabelTTFObj  string];`